# Error "'int' object is not subscriptable" though object is a list

Tags: python

I have a list called `chromosome` which contains 40 entries. Every entry is a binary number. For instance,

`chromosome = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]`

I need to convert each four binaries into an integer. For example, the integer list would be

`intlist = [12, 6 ... ]`

since `1100b = 12` and so on.

In order to solve the problem, I wrote the following Python function

```
def makeChromosomeInteger(chromosome, chrom_size):
    intstring = [0] * 10
    i = 0
    for j in range(0, 40, 4):
        intstring[i] = str(chromosome[j]) + str(chromosome[j+1]) + str(chromosome[j+2]) + str(chromosome[j+3])
        intstring[i] = int(intstring[i],2)
        i = i+1

    return intstring
```

This works in most cases - the function indeed converts each four binaries into integers. However, sooner or later I get the follow error message:

```
builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

and the problem seems to be `intstring[i] = int(intstring[i],2)`. I really have no idea why this happens. Neither `intstring` nor `chromosome` is an integer, so why can't I adress these lists?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: If there are any other clever ways to convert these entries I'm open for suggestions :)

Comment: There's no problem with the code you've shown.

Comment: You say the function mostly works, but sooner or later there is an error. This implies that the error is not with the function itself, but the code that is calling the function. Are you sure there is not a bug and it ends up passing an int rather than a list? Use a try/catch block and print the arguments to your function after a `TypeError.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, but here's a simplification:

```
chromosome = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

def makeIntList(chrom):
    intlist = []
    for j in range(0, len(chrom), 4):
        intlist.append(chrom[j]*8 + chrom[j+1]*4 + chrom[j+2]*2 + chrom[j+3])
    return intlist

intlist = makeIntList(chromosome)
print(intlist)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the simplification and for checking my code. You are right, my code is correct. It was some other function causing trouble.

Answer (score 1):

try the following instead for your code:

```
cs = [str(i) for i in chromosome]        # Convert to strings
grp = [cs[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(cs),4)] # Group into fours
ints = [int(''.join(g),2) for g in grp] # concatenate and convert as base 2.
```

Result for your sample are `[12, 6, 14, 0, 7, 8, 5, 0, 9, 3]`.